# Stopping a link on li hover

Tags: html, css

i don't want to show sub-menus when someone click inside li width

Right now it is coming on both li and a hover,so instead of li  i want to show it only on anchor tag hover

```
<style>

    #main-nav > ul > li > a.arrow {
        background: url("/assets/img/arrow-01.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        padding-right: 13px;
    }
    #main-nav > ul > li {
        float: left;
        padding: 0 0 16px 53px;
    }
    #main-nav > ul > li > a {
        color: #666;
        float: left;
        font-family: "proximanova-regular",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }

</style>
<nav id="main-nav">
<ul>
<li class="dropdownh insights drop-collapsed">
    <a href="/link/" class="arrow">Link</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: ... so don't use an `<a>` tag?

Comment: Sorry mate, but why do you want an anchor tag when you don't want to open a hyperlink when clicked? Could you please clarify the problem?

Comment: i dont want to open drop-down menus on li hover

Comment: `<a href="#" onclick="return false">Click!</a>` ?

Comment: Are you saying the width of your `li` is bigger than that of your `a` and you don't want to open a drop-down menu (which is not shown in code) when the mouse is over the `li` but not the `a`? Can you add your full markup and CSS?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<nav id="main-nav">
<ul>
<li class="dropdownh insights drop-collapsed">
    <a href="#" class="arrow">Link</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

or

```
# main-nav li {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: and what is wrong? I suggest put a cap or even remove a menu item

Comment: to link did not fire, I wrote but can put # he wants to hide the time I finished the second version))